# Sending data to external js file without it being visible to user (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, web

I want to send a variable from my controller to a view which then uses that variable as a parameter for a Javascript function found in an external file.  I know that, for example, I could pass the variable from the controller to the view using an array, and then use:

```
var quiz_key = <?php echo $quiz_key; ?>;
```

to pass the php variable to a javascript variable, which I could then use as a parameter for the function.  However, in doing this, the variable becomes visible if a user was to View Source and see the html.  Is there a way of accomplish this to where the variable would not be visible in this context?

Thanks in advance!  I'm still getting the hang of this so any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you are talking about JavaScript which is a client-side scripting language, which means that the client is always able to see your code. You could minify your JS.

Comment: @jldavis76 get this variable by ajax whel loading page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As `javascript` is not a server side language, but it runs on the client's browser, it cannot be completely hidden from him. You can hide this piece of code, obfuscate it, minimize it, but it can be found eventually.

You can set up a `node.js` server on the remote machine, connect to it, send it some variables, then process them and return to the client the result, but that's much more complex sollution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll Vote for using `Ajax`. `nodejs` is good but if you are in a hurry you should use `Ajax`.